# Firefox not loading wuFoo form in a toggled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A client has asked that I replace a contact from with a wufoo form. The div that holds the form is set to display none by default and then slideToggle when clicking on a "click here" div. This isnt a problem in chrome or safari but it doesnt work in firefox?

html:

```
<div class="brideclick">
                    Click here to email us
                    </div>

                    <div class="brideform pad-none">
                        <div id="wufoo-rei92q70h44gkt">
                        Fill out my <a href="link-to-wufoo-form">online form</a>.
                    </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">var rei92q70h44gkt;(function(d, t) {
                        var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
                        'userName':'theweddingaffair',
                        'formHash':'rei92q70h44gkt',
                        'autoResize':true,
                        'height':'2359',
                        'async':true,
                        'host':'wufoo.com',
                        'header':'show',
                        'ssl':true};
                        s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
                        s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
                        try { rei92q70h44gkt = new WufooForm();rei92q70h44gkt.initialize(options);rei92q70h44gkt.display(); } catch (e) {}};
                        var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
                        })(document, 'script');</script>
                    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$( ".brideclick" ).click(function() {
$( ".brideform" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
});
});
```

CSS:

```
.brideform{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in script:

```
$(document).on('click','.brideclick',function() {
    $( ".brideform" ).slideToggle( "slow");
});
```

Comment: no, nothing. The script executes as you'd expect and the frame opens but the iframe inside is set to height=0 ?

Comment: Then we can give it height using jquery. But this should be a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. I had to adjust the container heights in two places.

1. In the Wufoo code, and
2. In my script for the content expanding button.

Wufoo has a solution here: https://help.wufoo.com/articles/en_US/kb/Embed

I had to follow the instructions in the above as well as adjust the div container's height when "Answer" was clicked to get the form like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wufooClickText = document.querySelector('#wufoo-click-text');
var wufooFormContainer = document.querySelector('#wufoo-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
var answerLink = wufooClickText.querySelector('.answer');

    answerLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        wufooClickText.style.display = "none";
        wufooFormContainer.style.display = "block";
        wufooFormContainer.style.height ="2120px";
    });

</script>
```

This fixes it for me so that the entire form appeared on FF, Chrome & Safari when my Answer button was clicked. But, it's not perfect because the mobile form is longer because a two column item on desktop switches to single column on mobile as well as the field info is on mobile under the fields. So I had to make the container tall enough for mobile (as I didn't want a scroll bar) which leaves a lot of space on desktop under the form.